# Table Update Results In Every Entry Being Last Item in Source Table

Tags: sql, ssis

I am creating an SSIS package to update update a column in a destination database from an identical table in a source database. The issue I am having is that it seems when I run it the result is the destination database becomes the same entry for every single index. This entry happens to be identical to the last entry in the source table I am trying to update from.

I have an OLE DB Command with the following statement:

```
UPDATE [Archive-Announcements-test]
set UniqueID = ?, RunID = ?, Timestamp = ?, Priority = ?, Message = ?, PassingID = ?, EventID = ?, 
SeasonID = ?
```

I have also made sure to map them like so

[image: screenshot1]

Here is an example of what happens when to the destination table when it runs:

[image: screenshot2]

(This data is identical to the LAST entry of the source table)

Edit: I am trying to follow the following article on how to update one table from another [SQL Server UPDATE JOIN](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update-join/)

What I do not understand is how to apply this information to tables that exist in different databases(i.e. database1.table1 -> database2.table1).

Comment: Should not one or more of those column/parameter values be in a `WHERE` clause rather than `SET`. At the moment, *every* UPDATE is affecting *every* row.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This is what I was thinking as well and I am a bit confused on how to write the SQL to stop this from happening.

Comment: In English, the query says update all the values for SeasonID 18 and since you have 6 rows of SeasonID 18 after the query runs, they all have the same value. Without seeing your source data, it's hard to profile. My guess based on column names is that UniqueID (and maybe RunID) would be in your WHERE clause and you should have SeasonID in the SET section. What column *should* you be updating in your target database?

Comment: @billinkc sorry for the confusion. I am trying to update every column. I want to check for missing entries and add them if they are not there.